# Django: redirection if user is logged

Tags: django

Although there are many questions of this type, the answers that the collaborators have given do not work for me in any case.

I need to prevent logged in users from accessing the login page.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

views.py

```
def user_login(request):    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard')
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'
```

But it does not work. Please, help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

use `return redirect` instead of `HttpResponseRedirect`

```
def user_login(request):    
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('dashboard')
```